# Updated TeamCity: Now Won't Checkout Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, build-automation, teamcity

Well I didn't do a correct backup of my settings when I updated Team City and somehow lost all of my VCS roots but the rest of my settings for my projects are still there.

When I re-add my mercurial root, I test the connection and it succeeds, however when I try to run a build, it fails on checkout. Anyone know what this error means?

```
[Updating sources: agent side checkout...] Failed to perform checkout on agent: 'cmd /c hg pull <MERCURIAL URL>' command failed.
stderr: transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: connection ended unexpectedly

stdout: pulling from <MERCURIAL URL>
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
```

This was working before I mistakenly updated without backing up :(

I am using agent side checkout with a specified checkout directory (just like I was using before the update)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]: I updated tortoise hg / mercurial on the build server and got this error when trying to pull:

```
% hg --repository D:\Mercurial\Core pull --verbose https://<user email login>:<pw>@<kilnhg respository url>
pulling from https://<user email login>:<pw>@<kilnhg respository url>
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: connection ended unexpectedly
[command returned code 255 Thu Aug 11 15:17:17 2011]
```

I just tried again from tortoise hg and the pull succeeded. This is very strange :-/

Comment: Which version of Mercurial do you have installed, and do you know the version the server you're pulling from is running with?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't see why it would randomly stop working with the teamcity update. I did not update mercurial.

Comment: Yet Mercurial is the one that complains. Could the server you're pulling from be updated without you knowing it?

Comment: @Lasse - please see updated original post.

Comment: Aha, does the username and/or password contain a `@`-sign or a colon? I had problems at one point getting TeamCity to pull from my Kiln account, since the username was an email address, I had to escape it like %40 to get it to work. Could it be something similar here? See https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/994/valueerror-when-secureclicked

Comment: Yes username is an email address but teamcity changes it to %40 before calling it, however the address is formatted like this: <email login>:<pw>@<url with https:// truncated>

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem. I have tried all available versions of TortoiseHG on my Windows 7 (64) machine. I can't clone or pull anything from anywhere :)

What solved it for me is the "Use uncompressed transfer" check box in TortoiseHG gui.

Equal to "hg clone --uncompressed"

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a subtlety in your error message.  You're using Kiln, right?  I think this issue is explained on Kiln's [support site](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/935/connection-ended-unexpectedly-when-cloning-a-large-repository).  Can you manually pull from the repo to slowly pull chunks of revisions to see if it finishes with smaller sets using `hg pull -r 200` as shown on Kiln's support site?